# fail2ban wont start/Python syntax error

Tags: python, fail2ban

I installed fail2ban on my Ubuntu 18.04 server. But when i try to start the service i get this error.

> fail2ban.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
> fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  Failed to start Fail2Ban Service.

When i run the client as a user on another post suggested i get a Python syntax error:

```
> fail2ban-client -start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/fail2ban-client", line 34, in <module>
    from fail2ban.client.fail2banclient import exec_command_line, sys
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/fail2ban/client/fail2banclient.py", line 231
    def configureServer(self, async=True, phase=None):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can i fix this. I couldn't find any other info online regarding this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [a bug in fail2ban](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fail2ban/+bug/1794281) which affects Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and 18.10 but that's EOL already). For unknown reasons the relevant Ubuntu package maintainers have chosen not to fix this bug, even though a [patch](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/commit/ac9d5f61e7e9151f7518c26db192dd6d0bf56591) is available. You can try to patch the code yourself, or post on launchpad asking why it hasn't been fixed, or upgrade to 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while, but I had the same problem today.

I solved it by installing the latest version of fail2ban as a deb package from the fail2ban Github repo.

At the time of writing, I used wget to get this package:

```
wget https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/releases/download/0.11.2/fail2ban_0.11.2-1.upstream1_all.deb
```

and installed the package with `apt-get install -f ./fail2ban_0.11.2-1.upstream1_all.deb`

After that, I was able to start the fail2ban service and it works perfectly.

Comment: Downside of this approach is that you won't receive updates for the package anymore.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But I guess I won’t anyway until I upgrade to a more recent LTS release. 

I think the best approach is to always be on a non-outdated LTS release.